# Too narrow S-column in siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'm making a small table with numbers and units given with the `\SI{num}{unit}` call. However, the units stretches outside the table width, such that the `booktabs`lines (or any other line) looks too short.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\m}{\hat{m}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Some table}
    \begin{tabular}{
    r
    c
    S[table-format = 3.2]
    }
        \toprule
        Beskrivelse & Variabel & {Verdi}  \\
        \midrule
        Temperaturer & $T_{\m_2}^\text{rev}$ & 558.3\si{\kelvin} \\
        & $T_{\m_4}^\text{rev}$ & 542.3\si{\kelvin} \\
        Reversibelt arbeid & $W_{s,1}^\text{rev}$ & 237.5\si{\kilo\watt} \\
                           & $W_{s,2}^\text{rev}$ & 213.4\si{\kilo\watt} \\
        Arbeid & $W_{s,1}$ & 339.3\si{\kilo\watt} \\
               & $W_{s,2}$ & 304.9\si{\kilo\watt} \\
        Totalt & $W_s$ & 644.2 \si{\kilo\watt} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following

[image: short_lines]

As you can see, it doesn't look good. Any solution to this?

Comment: The `S` column is for _numbers only_: you are sticking in 'extra stuff' without allowing any space for it.

Comment: As @JosephWright explains: You will either use `table-space-text-post=\si{\kilo\watt}` or (recommended) a separate `s` column (it’s there for exactly this reason).

Comment: Is there a problem if you leave out the `table-format` option, i.e. just let `siunitx` center the content decimally without explicitly specifying the width?

Comment: @benwilfut In that case, the stagey is to centre the decimal marker. That works well if the number is approximately 'symmetrical', but is less good if it's not.

Comment: Isn't the normal recommentation to add the row units to the (row) stub instead? i.e. write `Temperaturer (\si{\kelvin})` and then remove the unit from the value itself.

Comment: @daleif You’d do that with the variable, e.g. `$T_{\m_2}^{\text{rev}}/\si{\kelvin}`, but in this case there is only one value per row, so you don’t even save space and it’s harder to read. I mostly see this with columns, though.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the variable column would be a good place to put it in this case. In general I'd advise users not to add units along with the data point, brings too much noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the questions comments, the answer would be:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english]{article}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\m}{\hat{m}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some table}
    \begin{tabular}{
    l
    c
    S[table-format = 3.1]      
    @{\,}
    s[table-unit-alignment = left]
    }
        \toprule
        Beskrivelse & Variabel & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Verdi} \\
        \midrule
        Temperaturer & $T_{\m_2}^\text{rev}$ & 558.3&\kelvin \\
        & $T_{\m_4}^\text{rev}$ & 542.3&\kelvin \\
        Reversibelt arbeid & $W_{s,1}^\text{rev}$ & 237.5&\kilo\watt \\
                           & $W_{s,2}^\text{rev}$ & 213.4&\kilo\watt \\
        Arbeid & $W_{s,1}$ & 339.3&\kilo\watt \\
               & $W_{s,2}$ & 304.9&\kilo\watt \\
        Totalt & $W_s$ & 644.2&\kilo\watt \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I find it strange to have the units centered and that far away from the numbers. For different mantissa lengths, this might be the correct way. But here, the mantissa is set to 3.2. The distance between number and unit can be shortened by the mantissa length 3.1. The alignment is changed by the column option `table-unit-alignment=left` (thanks to @Qrrbrbirlbel).

[image]

Comment: `S[table-format = 3.1] @{\,} s[table-alignment = left]` for the last two columns. The first column should be left aligned and `Verdi` should be `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Verdi}` so as to encompass both the final columns.

Comment: @egreg: thanks. adopted your comment. Overlooked that option in the doc.

Comment: @egreg Just to clarify: The `table-alignment` option sets the options `table-number-alignment`, `table-text-alignment` and `table-unit-alignment` to the same value. For a global declaration (i.e. `\sisetup` in the preamble) it’s better to use `table-unit-alignment`. In this particular case (no text in the `s` column) it doesn’t really matter.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel There are too many options! `;-)`. Better to correct, anyway.